# how to use printf without the \n?

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to print my array in one line but using "echo" is not working, it just cuts out half the output for some reason and the "printf" works only if I added the "%s\n" which make the output in a new line. How can I get the output to be in one line?

```
values=()
for line in $file; do
values+=($(echo "P>"${line[2]}))
done
printf "${values[@]}
```

Comment: `£file`? A typo?

Comment: `echo "${values[@]}"` should do what you want, but I'm almost sure that you're populating the array incorrectly.

Comment: Please provide a sample value of `values` and the expected output. In any case, it's not recommend that you use `printf` without an explicit format string.